# Error while installing VIM on Windows 7

Tags: python-2.7, vim, windows-7

I am using Windows 7 64 bit.  I've been playing around with Vim for a couple of days. I've been also trying to get python support for Vim on Windows 7, so I recently uninstalled Vim and Python 2.7 to see if reinstalling as 32-bit versions would do the trick automatically. But I can't seem to download and install Vim again using the executable installer for windows.  I used the executable installer the first time around, but this time I am getting this error:

```
Can't write: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe
```

[image: Vim Install Error]

```
Error opening file for writing:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe
```

[image: Error opening]

I deleted all the folders related to my previous Vim installation,  I figure that might have something to do with it.  Now I'm stuck, what should I do?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Right click the installer => run as Administrator?

Comment: It worked!  I can't believe it was so simple. Thank you so much! :)
Can you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access to *Program Files* is protected and evidently that installer is not elevating itself to require Administrator rights:

> Right click the installer => run as Administrator